# Why does $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \int^{x+1/n}_x F(t) dt = F(x)$ if F is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Why does $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \int^{x+1/n}_x F(t) dt = F(x)$, where $F(x) = \int^x_a f(t) dt$ for a Lebesgue integrable function $f$. How do I use continuity of $F$ here? I know that $F$ must be (absolutely) continuous but can't figure why that's important. Particularly, I can't figure how to get rid of the $n$ at the beginning when evaluating the limit.

Comment: You don't want to get rid of the $n$, but you should think of it as $1/(1/n)$. So, this is the limit of the average value of $F$ over vanishingly small intervals with $x$ as the left endpoint. Hint: Let $\epsilon > 0$, then use continuity of $F$ at $x$ to show that $F(x) - \epsilon < F(t) < F(x) + \epsilon$ for all $t \in [x,x + 1/n]$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Then bound the expression in the limit above and below by $F(x) \pm \epsilon$.

Comment: For why continuity is important, let $F(x)$ be the step function with a value of $1$ if $x > 0$, or $0$ if $x \le 0$.  Then the limit at $x = 0$ is $1$, but $F(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

We can define $$ G(x,n):=n\int_x^{x+1/n}F(t)dt - F(x) = n\int_x^{x+1/n}(F(t)-F(x))dt.$$ Let $\epsilon>0$ and by continuity at $x$, choose $N$ large enough so that $|F(y)-F(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|y-x|<1/N.$ Then we have $$ |G(x,n)|\le n\int_x^{x+1/n}|F(t)-F(x)|dt\le n\int_x^{x+1/n}\epsilon =\epsilon$$ for any $n>N.$ Thus $\lim_{n\to \infty} G(x,n) = 0$ which implies $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_x^{x+1/n}F(t)dt = F(x).$$

Answer (score 1):

As $F$ is continuous, we can represent the integral by the anti-derivative $A$ of $F$:
$$\int_x^{x+1/n} \!\!\!\!\!F(t)\,dt = A(x+1/n)-A(x)$$
so that
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} n \int^{x+1/n}_x \!\!\!\!\!F(t)\, dt 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{A(x+1/n)-A(x)}{1/n} \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\frac{A(x+\varepsilon)-A(x)}{\varepsilon} \\
&= A'(x) = F(x)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Then you need to know that the Riemann and Lebesgue integral of a continuous function coincide. Not easier than the original problem, I would think.